# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`IsShipping.ToAddress`' given input columns

Tags: r, dplyr, sparkr

I've used SparkR and dplyr in databricks and run the following code:

```
sdf=read.df("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Orders.csv", source = "csv", header="true", inferSchema = "true", delimiter = ";")
select(sdf,'RowNumber', 'CountOtherRegion', 'IsShipping.RailToAddress' ,'RegionFrom')
```

I've received the following error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`IsShipping.RailToAddress`' given input columns:

Is anyone can help me?